# Cannot map Interface to a class with AutoMapper, but manually I can

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper

I currently work on a small ASP.NET Core Web API Project. In my "VehicleModelsController" I have a class "VehicleModel":

```
       public class VehicleModel
       {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid VehicleMakeId { get; set; }         
        }
```

In the controller I also have a method for retrieving single vehicle model:

```
 // GET api/<controller>/Guid
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetModelById(Guid id)
    {
        var model = await Service.GetVehicleModelById(id);            
        if (model == null)
            return NotFound();

        var vehicleModel = new VehicleModelsController.VehicleModel()
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            VehicleMakeId = model.VehicleMakeId,
        };

        return Ok(vehicleModel);
    }
```

As you can see in this method I am calling "GetVehicleModelById" method in my Service which is defined as follows:

```
        public async Task<IVehicleModel> GetVehicleModelById(Guid vehicleModelId)
        {
        return await Repository.GetModelById(vehicleModelId);
        }
```

As you can see, it returns vehicle model object of type "IVehicleModel" which is an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface IVehicleModel
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    Guid VehicleMakeId { get; set; }        
}
```

This everything works when I'm doing manual mapping of IVehicleModel interface to a VehicleModel class in controller, as you already seen above, but when I try to do mapping with AutoMapper in controller, like this:

```
var vehicleModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<VehicleModelsController.VehicleModel>(model);
```

I get an error:

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Why is that so? Why can't I do the same with Automapper, what I already done manually?

I have defined mapping in my Mapping Profile class:

```
CreateMap<VehicleModelsController.VehicleModel, IVehicleModel>().ReverseMap();
```

so that is not a problem.

EDIT

This is my Mapping Profile class:

```
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    { 
      public MappingProfile()
      {
        CreateMap<VehicleModelsController.VehicleModel, IVehicleModel>().ReverseMap();
      }
    }
```

In "ConfigureServices" method in "Startup.cs" class I have:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

EDIT #2

This is exact error that I get:
[AutoMapper Mapping Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzD99.png)

Comment: I copy pasted Your code to my application and it's working. Something is not right with Your automapper configuration. Is any other mapping defined in that mapping profile working?

Comment: Can you please show your automapper class initialization?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya I added it

Comment: Update your startup code to point out your mappping class, services.AddAutoMapper(m=> m.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())); let me know if it works.

Comment: There is no no need to add the profile, just pass an assembly or a type. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya it still doesn't work, see new edit above

Comment: @Ivan, let me add detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [Automapper Source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), now you can pass an assembly containing your automapper profile implementation  or any type from that assembly.

Also mentioned in [ReadMe page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md)

To use, with an IServiceCollection instance and one or more assemblies:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(assembly1, assembly2 /*, ...*/);
```

or marker types:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(type1, type2 /*, ...*/);
```

So you can pass Startup.cs as marker type as below

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Or your assembly containing Automapper implementation class.